# How to hide an entity property in Symfony4 api-platform

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have this entity

```
/**
* @ApiResource(
*       collectionOperations={
*           "get"={
*               "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
*           },
*           "post"={
*               "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
*           }
*       },
*       itemOperations={
*       "get"={
*               "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object.getUser() == user"
*           },
*           "put"={
*               "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object.getUser() == user"
*          },
*           "delete"={
*               "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object.getUser() == user"
*          }
*       }
* )
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeedRepository")
*/
class Feed implements AuthoredEntityInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="feeds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2083, unique=true)
 */
private $url;

//various getters and setters

}
```

The related User entity implements UserInterface. This entity implements an interface I use to auto populate the user field with the logged user.

The auto generated /api/feeds POST endpoint expects 3 parameters: user, name and url.

I want to exclude the parameter user from the endpoint (because auto-generated internally). I know I could just not to use it but this is causing problems in testing where I get this message:

**Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?)**

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony Serializer supports `@Groups` annotation, which gives you support to hide or show fields based on given group.

There is example in API Platform docs https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 */
class Book
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @Groups("write")
     */
    public $author;

    // ...
}
```